# what is the weak * convergence limit of $|\cos(nx)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

When I was waiting for a bus, suddenly a question occured in my mind: If $g_n$ weakly star converge to $0$ in $L^{\infty}$, then is it true that $|g_n|$ weakly start converge to $0$? Then I realize clearly $\cos(nx)$ weakly star converges to $0$, since it is well-known that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int f(x)\cos(nx) dx=0 $$ for any $L^1$ function $f$. However, from picture clearly $|\cos(nx)|$ doesn't weakly star converge to $0$.

Then I'm puzzled：what is the weak star convergent limit of $|\cos(nx)|$? That is, given any $L^1$ function $f$, what is the limit of $\int f(x) |\cos(nx)|dx$?

Can anyone tell me the answer and refer me to a proof? I'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is the constant function $\frac 2\pi$.

1. Take $f$ to be an indicator of an interval $[0,a]$.

$$\int f(x) |\cos(nx)| dx = \int_{[0,a]}  |\cos(nx)|dx =\frac{1}{n} \int_0^{na} |\cos(y)|dy \sim \frac 1n  2\times \frac{na}{\pi}=2a/\pi.$$

Therefore for any indicator of an interval $[a,b]$,

$$\int f(x) |\cos(nx)|dx\to \frac{2}{\pi} (b-a)=\frac 2\pi \int f dx.$$

This extends to all step functions.

2. Let $f$ be any function in $L^1$. Then there exists a sequence of step functions converging to $f$ in $L^1$. For each such step function $\phi_N$, we have

$$ \int \phi_N |\cos(nx)| dx \to \frac 2\pi \int \phi_N dx.$$

Therefore

$$ \begin{align*}& \left|\int f |\cos(nx)|dx - \frac 2\pi \int f dx \right |  \\& \le \|f-\phi_N\|_1 +\left|\int \phi_N |\cos(nx)| dx -\frac 2\pi \int \phi_N dx \right|+\frac{2}{\pi} \|\phi_N - f\|_1.\end{align*}$$

Letting $n\to\infty$ then $N\to\infty$ completes the proof.

Comment: it's a joke ? you write $\int g(x) dx$ too ? come on

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't even try this simple way.